# Assigning a default value for a type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

What I want to do is to assign default values for all properties in my custom type, if it's not defined.

I've done this:

```
// my custom type with all optional properties
type MyType = {
  // a example property:
  str?: string
}
// imagine I have hundreds of properties, I can't assign all of them one by one
// so I created a object for default values
const defaultValuesForMyType: MyType = {
  str: "hello world!"
}

// passes a string to do something
// imagine it's a function in other API that I can't change
function doThingsWithString(str: string): void {
  // do something, doesn't matter, for example:
  console.log(str);
}

// passes a object with my custom type
function driver(inputObject: MyType) {
  const finalObject: MyType = { ...defaultValuesForMyType, ...inputObject };
  doThingsWithString(finalObject.str);
}
```

but VS Code shows me:

```
doThingsWithString(finalObject.str);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2345)
const finalObject: {
    str?: string | undefined;
}
```

I thought finalObject is 100% not `undefined`?

#### edited:

@jcalz's answer works!

I've noticed that it's classes' problem, I'm sorry

```
// my custom type with all optional properties
type MyType = {
  // a example property:
  str?: string
}
// imagine I have hundreds of properties, I can't assign all of them one by one
// so I created a object for default values
const defaultValuesForMyType = {
  str: "hello world!"
}

// passes a string to do something
// imagine it's a function in other API that I can't change
function doThingsWithString(str: string): void {
  // do something, doesn't matter, for example:
  console.log(str);
}

class TestClass {
  propObject;

  driver(inputObject: MyType) {
    this.propObject = { ...defaultValuesForMyType, ...inputObject };
    doThingsWithString(this.propObject.str);
  }
}
```

No error, but VS Code says `TestClass#propObject` is `any` now

Comment: Try remove the `: MyType` part from `const defaultValuesForMyType: MyType = {…}`

Comment: It's `any` because you didn't annotate it and because you didn't initialize it.  You should do those things, possibly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2vdjw).  I don't really understand why this isn't a followup question, since it's just the next thing you hit after clearing up the problem here.  I'll edit my answer but I'm hoping you don't just edit to ask about the next problem after this one.

Answer (score 1):

You have [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `defaultValuesForMyType` to be `MyType`, so that's all the compiler knows about `defaultValuesForMyType`.  Any more specific information from the initializing object literal has been lost.  The `str` property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties). This allows you to `delete` the `str` property, which is presumably the reason why one would make such an annotation.  As far as the compiler knows or cares, `str` might be `string` or `undefined`.

If you want the compiler to know that the `str` property is `string` and never `undefined`, then you'd be better off not annotating at all.  Just let the compiler [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) its type:

```
const defaultValuesForMyType = {
    str: "hello world!"
}
/* const defaultValuesForMyType: {
    str: string;
} */
```

After this the compiler will understand that [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `defaultValuesForMyType` and a `MyType` into a new object will result in a definite `string` value for the `str` property:

```
function driver(inputObject: MyType) {
    const finalObject = { ...defaultValuesForMyType, ...inputObject };
    // const finalObject: {  str: string; }
    doThingsWithString(finalObject.str); // okay
}
```

To get this working inside a class, be sure to [annotate the type of your field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields).  Because it's not initialized in the constructor, it should probably make it [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties):

```
class TestClass {
    propObject?: Required<MyType>; // annotate

    driver(inputObject: MyType) {
        this.propObject = { ...defaultValuesForMyType, ...inputObject };
        doThingsWithString(this.propObject.str);
    }
}
```

Note that I wrote the relevant type as `Required<MyType>` using [the `Required` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) to generate a version of `MyType` where all the properties are required.  You could also write `{str: string}` just as easily, but if you have hundreds of properties presumably `Required<MyType>` will scale better.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EtRYjSowCgANbkSCdRKUHafcR8JAAYRXu2jygMWEbSGs8kOjMHJwrG3KnsI3vYvqY-qDY7DokmuCjM3KShuCC1B5HqAqaFpmQw5GMBR5jgBbpsWL7JuWlY-ko5w9o4ZIUgOdJ-gBnCHq+E6GshSiuM4QA)

Comment: Wait it works in this demo, with all types maintaining correct; but not in my original project, all its types were lost. I'll edit my question and post some of my original project's code later

Comment: So your code wasn't a [mre]? ‍♂️ No idea how to proceed from here I guess.

Comment: no no no, maybe because the demo is small, so VS Code understand, my project is bigger, so it gave up

Comment: sorry... I found that it only does not work in my `class`.... updated my question